# how to clear collectionview selection in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, collectionview

On Page#1, i have a collectionview with text/string items list. If you tap a a item, it will get the current tapped text/string and send to Page#2. sound simple

**issue I am having:** if you tap on item#1, then it will send item#1 to page2, this part working fine. But on page#2, if you hit back button, and tap on item#1 again.. than nothing happens, it doesnt go to page#2

**Fix:** i think i need to somehow clear tap selection, and than send the item to page#2. but im not sure how to do this

On Page#1, i have a simple collectionview. Collection view contains text/string list

```
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MyListItem}"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentView>
                        <!-- Body -->
                        <Grid Padding="0">
                            <Frame CornerRadius="3" BorderColor="#f2f4f5" HasShadow="True">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Source="icon_about"
                                               WidthRequest="25"  />
                                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
                                        <Label VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                    FontSize="16" 
                                                    Text="{Binding .}" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
```

back end code to handle selection is:

```
    private async void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var previous = e.PreviousSelection.FirstOrDefault();
        var current = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault();

        var route = $"{ nameof(Page2) }?URLCardType={current}";
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route);
        
        //clear selection 
        ((CollectionView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

**Update**  `((CollectionView)sender).SelectedItem = null;` fixed the issue of clearing selected item but `CollectionView_SelectionChanged` method is get run twice on single tap. why? this is all the code i have

Comment: set `SelectedItem` to null

Comment: @Jason, thanks for getting back to me. I added selectedItem to null code, but than no value get passed to next page. also i notcied on single tap, my method `CollectionView_SelectionChanged` get run twice. which is maybe why  setting `current` to null

Comment: try putting it after the navigation

Comment: that worked. but `CollectionView_SelectionChanged` is still getting run twice on single tap. so its trying to go to page2 twice

Answer (score 2):

@jason thanks, this worked for me. i just had to check if selection item is null than do nothing

```
  private async void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         var MyCollectionView = sender as CollectionView;  
            if (MyCollectionView.SelectedItem == null)
                return;

        var previous = e.PreviousSelection.FirstOrDefault();
        var current = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault();

        var route = $"{ nameof(Page2) }?URLCardType={current}";
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route);
        
        //clear selection 
       MyCollectionView.SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but since there is no accepted answer and there is an  update:

> ((CollectionView)sender).SelectedItem = null; fixed the issue of
> clearing selected item but CollectionView_SelectionChanged method is
> get run twice on single tap. why? this is all the code i have

looking for one I've decided to explain why the following code has a certain side-effect that, historically speaking, dates back to Visual Basic 6:

```
private void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CurrentSelection != null)
    {
        var current = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault();

        // do something useful with current
        
        //clear selection 
        ((CollectionView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
    }
}
```

The above code resembles the OP's code but also checks `e.CurrentSelection` for `null`, which is a nice and safe thing to do.

Nevertheless, it also causes the `SelectionChanged` event to fire again (since `SelectedItem` is changed programmatically) and the same event handler to be called *twice*. And while the humble programmer thinks he/she is on the safe side since `e.CurrentSelection` is checked for `null` the ugly truth is that he/she isn't because for some reason known only by the ancient gods, `e.CurrentSelection` is NOT null the second time and the code breaks with a `NullPointerException`.

So, if one needs to set the selected item to `null` then one must double check for `null`, for example:

```
private void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CurrentSelection != null)
    {
        var current = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault();

        // double check for null because the event handler will be called twice 
        // (the second time when SelectedItem is set to null BELOW) in which 
        // case e.CurrentSelection is NOT null
        if (current != null)
        {
            // do something useful with current
            ((CollectionView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this answers both the original question and the updated one and helps people clear the CollectionView's SelectedItem in a (somewhat) safe manner.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution that worked for me.
Setting to null did not do the trick, it was causing all kinds of
weird stuff.

```
  private void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var itemselected = e.CurrentSelection[0] as ProductsItem;
       if (itemselected != null)
        Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(SelectedProductPage));

       //Setting the selected item to an emptyviewproperty after navigation
        CollectionList.SelectedItem = SelectableItemsView.EmptyViewProperty;
    }
```